# Dozer issue: No read or write method found for field (status) in class

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

Here is my mapping in the dozermap.xml file:

```
<mapping type="one-way">
      <class-a>com.models.ClassA</class-a>
      <class-b>com.models.ClassB</class-b>
        <field custom-converter="com.models.helpers.CustomConverterDemo">
            <a>status</a>
            <b>status</b>
        </field>
        <field-exclude type="one-way">
            <a>createdOn</a>
            <b>createdOn</b>
        </field-exclude>
</mapping>
```

The mapping is working fine and this error is happening only when I try to run junit tests.

The stack trace:

```
org.dozer.MappingException: No read or write method found for field (status) in class (class com.models.TestModel)
at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.determinePropertyType(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:319)
at org.dozer.propertydescriptor.GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.getPropertyType(GetterSetterPropertyDescriptor.java:76)
at org.dozer.fieldmap.FieldMap.getDestFieldType(FieldMap.java:117)
at org.dozer.util.MappingUtils.applyGlobalCopyByReference(MappingUtils.java:212)
at org.dozer.loader.MappingsParser.processMappings(MappingsParser.java:168)
at org.dozer.loader.CustomMappingsLoader.load(CustomMappingsLoader.java:49)
at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.loadCustomMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:213)
at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.initMappings(DozerBeanMapper.java:315)
at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.getMappingProcessor(DozerBeanMapper.java:192)
at org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper.map(DozerBeanMapper.java:120)
at com.helpers.GeneralHelper.mapDomainModelToKey(GeneralHelper.java:226)
at com.helpers.GeneralHelper.updateKeys(GeneralHelper.java:130)
at com.helpers.GeneralHelperTest.addKeys(GeneralHelperTest.java:295)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
```

Comment: Please add sufficient information with classes involved and logs.

Comment: Ok, so I put some more details about the issue

Answer (score 0):

From the log messages, it appears that you do not have mappings for `com.models.TestModel` class. You can either add relevant mapping in test resources are can do it in your test class Setup. Dozer [docs](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/apimappings.html) has some examples.

Comment: why should i add another xml file in the junit tests?? It should be working with the existing one.And i do have mappings for Testmodel class.

Comment: Above mapping file does not show TestModel mapping. Can you make sure that the mapping which contains TestModel is in classpath when you run the test ? Also ensure that you have relevant setter methods in TestModel class.